# Customized Checkbox still shows original checkbox on top of custom control when hovered

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using the customized Checkbox example that Qt posted with QtQuick 2.15 with Qt 6.2.1:

```
    CheckBox {
    id: control
    text: qsTr("CheckBox")
    checked: true

    indicator: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 26
        implicitHeight: 26
        x: control.leftPadding
        y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
        radius: 3
        border.color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"

        Rectangle {
            width: 14
            height: 14
            x: 6
            y: 6
            radius: 2
            color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
            visible: control.checked
        }
    }

    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        leftPadding: control.indicator.width + control.spacing
    }
}
```

Using that control as is has some weird effects. When the control is hovered, the old checkobx box shows up as well as the old indicator when clicked.

[image] // Checked

[image] // Checked & Hovered

[image] // Unchecked & Hovered

[image] // No mouse interaction

This is weird, I'm not able to pinpoint the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with a Button object. Whenever I hovered or clicked the button, a default rectangle would appear.

I solved it by changing my controls import to a specific style.

```
import QtQuick.Controls.<Insert Style> 2.15
```

I tried your code and it seemed to solve the issue too. Tested with both ***5.15.2*** and ***6.5.0***.

This seemed to be the [issue](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customization-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Found the same issue here. I solved it by using the QuickControls CheckDelegate as a base. Not ideal, but works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you set hoverEnabled:false. It is by default set to true in 6.x, what was probably not the case in 5.x.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33423087)